# The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have data in xml format in SQL Server. Now I am trying to find out single record based on my query. I am putting my code below,

```sql
declare @xml xml
declare @ID varchar
set @ID = '1'
set @xml = '
<row>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <name>OM</name>
</row>
<row>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <name>JAI</name>
</row>
<row>
    <Id>2</Id>
    <name>JAGDISH</name>
</row>
'
```

When I am executing my query, then it gives me a proper result (xml node):

```
Select @xml.query('/row[Id="1"]');
```

But When I am concatenating @ID to query, then it gives me an error:

```
Select @xml.query('/row[Id='+ @ID +']');
```

The error is:

> The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need the [sql:variable()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-extension-functions-sql-variable) XQuery extension function to refer to a variable. This function (quote from the link) "exposes a variable that contains a SQL relational value inside an XQuery expression".

```
Select @xml.query('/row[Id=sql:variable("@ID")]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamic SQL:

```
IF TRY_PARSE(@ID AS INT) IS NULL
   THROW 50000, 'ID is not integer',1;


DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Select @xml.query(''/row[Id=<placeholder>]'')';

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '<placeholder>', @Id);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@xml XML', @xml;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/RLVE55820)**

Warning!

Be aware that you should always check user input.